# Install JavaFx to Eclipse on Mac

Tags: eclipse, javafx, macos-catalina

I'm trying to install JavaFx to Eclipse in Mac OS. But I can't find the jfxswt.jar file in /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_09.jdk/Contents/Home/. 
Anyone know the location of that file or any other way to install JavaFx to Eclipse in Mac OS.?

Comment: Why do you use such an ancient Java version? I doubt you will still find proper support for that. Did you have a look here? https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/

Answer (score 2):

You can try to go to `Help` -> `Eclipse Marketplace` and search for `e(fx)clipse` and then click on Install, they will ask you to relaunch Eclipse.

Then you can go to `File` -> `new` -> `Other` and select the folder `JavaFx` -> `JavaFx Project`.

If after that the `import javafx` doesn't work, you can go to this website :
`https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/` and download the support release for javaFX based on your OS. Then right click on your Eclipse project `properties` -> `Java Build Path` -> `Class Path` -> `Add external JARs...` and then add the lib file you just download, that should do the job.